# Что быстрее: условная операция ?: или if/else

Tags: java

В Java есть два типа работы с условием: это традиционная конструкция if/else и условная операция condition ? value1 : value2. Какой способ быстрее или они одинаковы?

Традиционный

```
int result;
if (condition) {
  result = 0;
} else {
  result = 1;
}
```

Условная операция

```
int result = (condition)? 0: 1;
```

Comment: На деле, если бы поменьше людей задавалось вопросами о производительности `?:`, а побольше - вопросами о том, как писать **действительно качественный код,** было бы намного лучше.

Comment: .

    int result=((Boolean) (2>3)).compareTo(true);

Comment: С одной стороны вопрос бессмысленный, а с другой может подтолкнуть автора вопроса к изучению принципов компиляции и самостоятельному ответу (осознанию), что в **правильном** компиляторе резудьтат будет одинаков.

Comment: это называется "программерский сахар", т.е просто сокращенная форма записи, в инэте достаточно холиваров по этому поводу. имхо, его стоит применять только в "правильный" ситуациях, когда это не усложнит читаемость кода. Для компилятора обе формы одинаковые.. =), а вопрос недалеко по смыслу от "если я не буду комментировать код, он будет быстрее компилироваться?")))

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Если заглянуть в дизассемблер у С++ для if и ? генерируется одинаковый код. В Java тоже самое, генерируется одинаковый код в *.class.

Comment: неистово плюсую :)
это синтаксический сахар, не более)

Answer (score 3):

Эээм,

Смотря на чем пишите, если язык компилируемый, то разницы нет.
Если же все это выполняется в реал тайме, то понятно, что ?: будет меньше занимать места => обработка займет меньше времени.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо этого есть еще и различные соглашение.
В частности - "Человек пишет для человека", а машина сама скомпилирует понятней для нее. Есть компиляторы, есть сборщики и т.п.
Поэтому пишите так как код будет более читабельный!

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, разницы в конечном итоге не будет. Как читается лучше, так и пиши.